# Does usb 2.0 port differs from usb 3.0 port on pc case

Tags: usb, case

My main board has only usb 3.0 ports. If I connect those ports to USB 2.0 ports on pc case will they work as USB 3.0 port (with full speed) or will they work as USB 2.0 ports (with lower bandwith). In other words do 2.0 ports differt from 3.0 ports on computer casing?

Answer (score 1):

The ports do differ.

The USB 3.0 port contains extra pins for SuperSpeed communication. Without these pins, devices can only communicate at USB 2.0 speeds.